# Declare variable and use in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following

```
declare @MyField varchar(255);
set @MyField = 'MyDatabaseField';

select distinct Table.@MyField
from Table
```

This results in the error `Incorrect syntax near @MyField`. Then I tried:

```
select distinct Table.['+@MyField+']
from Table
```

However, this results in an `Incorrect column name` error.

How do I correctly use the @MyField in this query? I'm on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Please try executing by building a string.

```
declare @MyField varchar(255);
set @MyField = 'MyDatabaseField';

exec ('select distinct Table.'+@MyField+' from Table')
```

Refer [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), [Using sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You should use dynamic SQL to achieve that. You can use `sp_executesql` stored proc to do that. Please not that I changed your variable declaration to **N**VARCHAR.

```
declare @MyField nvarchar(255)
set @MyField = N'MyDatabaseField'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select distinct ' + @MyField + N' from TableName'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```